# Something wrong with BFS maze solving algorithm in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, breadth-first-search, maze

http://ideone.com/QXyVzR

The above link contains a program I wrote to solve mazes using a BFS algorithm. The maze is represented as a 2D array, initially passed in as numbers, (0's represent an empty block which can be visited, any other number represent a "wall" block), and then converted into a record type which I defined, which keeps track of various data:

```
type mazeBlock = {
    walkable   : bool;
    isFinish   : bool;
    visited    : bool;
    prevCoordinate : int * int
}
```

The output is a list of ordered pairs (coordinates/indices) which trace a shortest path through the maze from the start to the finish, the coordinates of which are both passed in as parameters.

It works fine for smaller mazes with low branching factor, but when I test it on larger mazes (say 16 x 16 or larger), especially on ones with no walls(high branching factor) it takes up a LOT of time and memory. I am wondering if this is inherent to the algorithm or related to the way I implemented it. Can any OCaml hackers out there offer me their expertise?

Also, I have very little experience with OCaml so any advice on how to improve the code stylistically would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

EDIT:

http://ideone.com/W0leMv

Here is an cleaned-up, edited version of the program. I fixed some stylistic issues, but I didn't change the semantics. As usual, the second test still takes up a huge amount of resources and cannot seem to finish at all. Still seeking help on this issue...

EDIT2:

SOLVED. Thanks so much to both answerers. Here is the final code:

http://ideone.com/3qAWnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your critical section, that is `mazeSolverLoop`, you should only visited elements that have not been visited before. When you take the element from the queue, you should first check if the element has been visited, and in that case do nothing but recurse to get the next element. This is precisely what makes the good time complexity of the algorithm (you never visit a place twice).

Otherwise, yes, your OCaml style could be improved. Some remarks:

- the convention in OCaml-land is rather to `write_like_this` instead of `writeLikeThis`. I recommend that you follow it, but admittedly that is a matter of taste and not an objective criterion.
- there is no point in returning a datastructure if it is a mutable structure that was updated; why do you make a point to always return a `(grid, pair)` queue, when it is exactly the same as the input? You could just have those functions return `unit` and have code that is simpler and easier to read.
- the abstraction level allowed by pairs is good and you should preserve it; you currently don't. There is no point in writing for example, `let (foo, bar) = dimension grid in if in_bounds pos (foo, bar)`. Just name the dimension `dim` instead of `(foo, bar)`, it makes no sense to split it in two components if you don't need them separately. Remark that for the neighbor, you do use `neighborX` and `neighborY` for array access for now, but that is a style mistake: you should have auxiliary functions to get and set values in an array, taking a pair as input, so that you don't have to destruct the pair in the main function. Try to keep all the code inside a single function at the same level of abstraction: all working on separate coordinates, or all working on pairs (named as such instead of being constructed/deconstructed all the time).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the convention. I will fix those later. About the queue: by the way I wrote the `targetForVisitation` function (hopefully I did it correctly?), all dequeued elements are guaranteed to be not visited; which is why I am confused about the second test eating up all my memory whenever I run it...

Comment: I don't think the test in `targetForVisitation` is sufficient. If the current position A has neighbors B and C, which both have a common neighbor D, you will visit B, add all its neighbor (including D), then visit C, and add D again because it has not yet been visited. This means you will traverse D more than once in the main loop. And it is not even the case that, on the second traversal, all its neighbors will have been marked visited.

Comment: PS: I implemented the change I described and the code goes massively faster.

Comment: Wow... I cannot believe that I missed such a crucial detail. The amount of pointless repetitions increase almost exponentially, no wonder the code slows down so much. I think I'll fix it by marking the nodes when enqueueing (as neighbors) rather than dequeueing them. Can you put what you said in the comment into your answer, and I will choose it right away? Thanks a ton!

Comment: In the general case (Dijsktra), it is important to leave not-yet-visited neighbors not-visited when you add them to the work queue, because you may find a shorter distance for them from another node later. Therefore, the fix I suggested is better than the one you implemented. However, I suspect that in the restricted case where all distances are exactly `1`, this is equivalent.

Comment: Good point. For a grid like this though, the case that a later-discovered path is shorter than a previous one is impossible, so it's fine. I'd also like the queue to be as small as possible, in order to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, for an N x N grid with no walls you have a graph with N^2 nodes and roughly 4*N^2 edges. These don't seem like big numbers for N = 16.

I'd say the only trick is to make sure you track visited nodes properly. I skimmed your code and don't see anything obviously wrong in the way you're doing it.

Here is a good OCaml idiom. Your code says:

```
let isFinish1 = mazeGrid.(currentX).(currentY).isFinish in
let prevCoordinate1 = mazeGrid.(currentX).(currentY).prevCoordinate in
mazeGrid.(currentX).(currentY) <-
    { walkable = true;
     isFinish = isFinish1;
     visited = true;
     prevCoordinate = prevCoordinate1}
```

You can say this a little more economically as follows:

```
mazeGrid.(currentX).(currentY) <-
    { mazeGrid.(currentX).(currentY) with visited = true }
```

Comment: I didn't know about this before. Thank you!